# React: Using State to change the appearance of a circle component when a button component is pressed

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to change the appearance of a circle component when it's selected by a button in another component. they both have to change appearance when selected.  I'm running into problems with state and I'm kinda confused. Also, I've been trying to use the onClick functionality, but can't seem to get it right. Any help will be appreciated

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import CircleSelector from "./CircleSelector";
import Circles from "./Circles";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.addActiveClass = this.addActiveClass.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      active: false
    };
  }

  toggleClass() {
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({ active: !currentState });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">test </header>
        <main>
          <CircleSelector
            className={this.state.active ? "selected" : null}
            onClick={this.toggleClass}
          />
          <Circles />
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

CircleSelector.js

```
import React from "react";

function CircleSelector(props) {
  return (
    <div className="CircleSelector">
      <button className="selected">Select Circle 1</button>
      <button>Select Circle 2</button>
      <button>Select Circle 3</button>
      <button>Select Circle 4</button>
    </div>
  );
}

// Must export the component's function (or class)
export default CircleSelector;
```

Circles.js

```
import React from "react";

function Circles(props) {
  return (
    <div className="Circles">
      <div className="selected">1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
    </div>
  );
}

// Must export the component's function (or class)
export default Circles;
```

App.css

```
body,
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.App {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.App-header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.App main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.CircleSelector {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 4px solid purple;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome Marco, this appears to be an assignment from school. I recommend not making that obvious next time.

Comment: You aren't accessing your props inside CircleSelector.js. You need something like props.className instead of className='selected'

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though your problem may be from `toggleClass`. When the function executes `onClick`, it is using `this` from inside the button's scope, not the class scope.

Try binding the function like so:

```
      <CircleSelector
        className={this.state.active ? "selected" : null}
        onClick={this.toggleClass.bind(this)}
      />
```

You can read more and find more potential solutions to the scope issue [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56/)